# Query a object list and return only a specific field from every (python/pymongo)

Tags: python, discord.py, pymongo

I have this list here:

```py
itemUserList = [
    {"Name": "Lucky Charm", "Amount": 0, "Active?": "No", "Timer": 0},
    {"Name": "Elite User", "Amount": 0, "Active?": "No", "Timer": 0},
    {"Name": "Random Card", "Amount": 0, "Active?": "No", "Timer": 0},
    {"Name": "Luck Booster", "Amount": 0, "Active?": "No", "Timer": 0}
]
```

And I added it to a document in my MongoDb collections:

[image]

What I want to do now is to query the "Items" query and returning the "Name" field and the "Amount" field from every object. Is there an easy way to do this?

What I tried:

```py
UserItems = userBase.find_one({"_id": userid})["Items"]
ActualItems = UserItems[0:]["Name"]
print(ActualItems)
```

It would probably work if I do it with a for loop or so and add the names and amounts to an list. But isn't there a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you will need to loop through the list to be able to print all element with their name and amount like this:

```py
for item in UserItems:
    print(f"item: {item['Name']}, amount: {item['Amount']}")
```